# Conditional CSS3... if that's even what it's called

Tags: css, conditional-statements, transition

I have a search bar with some social media buttons just to the side of it. I wanted to use the CSS3 Transition property to have the bar change in width when I click on it but I need the buttons to shift as well. This is what I have so far

```
#s
{
transition: width 2s;
-moz-transition: width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: width 2s; /* Opera */
}

#s:focus {
width:110px;
}

.search input[type="text"], .widget_search input[type="text"] {
background-image: url(api/images/icons/search.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 8px 50%;
padding-left: 25px;
width: 80%;
-moz-border-radius: 1em;
-webkit-border-radius: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
}

#searchform #searchsubmit {
clear: both;
display: block;
margin: 10px 0;
}
```

The text field changes width just fine but to reiterate, I want to know if I can change the position of the buttons next to the text field when I click in the text field.

```
<div id="header-widget-area" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <div id="pc_info_widget_designfolio-4" class="widget pc_info_widget">
        <a class="sm-icon" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/TheRedBalloonToyStore">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" src="http://redballoontoystore.com/w/wp-content/themes/designfolio/images/facebook.png">
        </a>
        <a class="sm-icon" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/RBToyStore">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter" src="http://redballoontoystore.com/w/wp-content/themes/designfolio/images/twitter.png">
        </a>
        <div class="search">
            <form id="searchform" action="http://redballoontoystore.com/w/" method="get" role="search">
                <span>
                <input id="s" type="text" name="s" size="10" value="" placeholder="Search…">
                <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Search">
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS works on HTML, which we don't have. This makes it almost impossible to post anything other than guesses. Incidentally, a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) goes a *long way* to getting better answers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y39A3/ here a demo, but I don't see "social media buttons just to the side of it" Could you modify the demo?

Comment: I am trying, I am entering in all of the CSS that I see but for some reason it's not doing it in the demo

Comment: I entered in the whole stylesheet and it didn't even work, the site right now is http://redballoontoystore.com/w

Answer (score 1):

Because the elements you want to move in response to focusing on the `input` appear *earlier* in the DOM, which is contrary to the way CSS selects elements (it can only select elements *later* in the DOM), the only way I could implement this was to size the `a` elements (that contain the images) at 48% of the width of the parent `div`; and center the images within their parent `a` elements.

This way as the width of the parent changes in response to the focus, the size of the `a` increases and, as the images are centered within those `a` elements, their position changes too. The down-side is that the parent div has to adjust its width in response to the focus of a child element, and the only way that's possible is if the `div` is of display `inline`, `inline-block` (or floated or absolutely-positioned).

I also slightly-amended your transition approach, the vendor-prefixes should precede the non-vendor prefixed version (that way the 'final release' transition overrides the vendor-prefixed versions). Anyway, adjust to taste, and I *hope* that this is of some use to you:

```
#header-widget-area {
    border: 1px solid #000; /* to help visualise the space/size of the element */
    display: inline-block; /* to 'collapse' the element to the size of its children */
}

#s {
    width: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

#s:focus {
    width: 110px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GSgYA/1/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post that. I couldn't get the buttons to be in line like it is on the site for some reason, but the site is http://redballoontoystore.com/w

Comment: If you're done with helping that's cool and I appreciate it, I'll see if I can use what you posted to get it to work

Comment: I'm happy to help; but without the actual CSS (and looking at your site you've got quite a few stylesheets) it's almost impossible. And editing your website on the fly is not a challenge for this time of night (practically midnight, UK). If you can gather together the all the applicable CSS and add that to the question I'll definitely have another look, though). Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `#s:focus + button` and `#s:focus + button + button`. Remember, the `+` selector element means "next sibling".

Comment: Would I need to declare another transition for those buttons?

Comment: How do I get the CSS to _say_ "move these buttons over to the left when this other text field is clicked on"?

Comment: When I add a rule that says `#s:focus { width: 110px }` on your site and click on the search field, the buttons do move over. After all, they're inline elements.

Comment: Did you do that without adding the transition?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't actually do the transition.